# Check if lat/long point is within a set of polygons using google maps

Tags: google-maps, point-in-polygon

I know how to do the above using Esri (Query task on shapefile), but can this also be done using Google Maps?  Do I have to query each polygon or is there one method to query a set of polygons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Google maps API does not already provide a method for checking points in polygons.
After researching a bit I stumbled across the Ray-casting algorithm which will determine if an X-Y coordinate is inside a plotted shape. This will translate to latitude and longitude. The following extends the google.maps.polygon.prototype to use this algorithm. Simply include this code at a point in the code after google.maps has loaded:

```
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains = function (point) {
    var crossings = 0,
        path = this.getPath();

    // for each edge
    for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
        var a = path.getAt(i),
            j = i + 1;
        if (j >= path.getLength()) {
            j = 0;
        }
        var b = path.getAt(j);
        if (rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b)) {
            crossings++;
        }
    }

    // odd number of crossings?
    return (crossings % 2 == 1);

    function rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b) {
        var px = point.lng(),
            py = point.lat(),
            ax = a.lng(),
            ay = a.lat(),
            bx = b.lng(),
            by = b.lat();
        if (ay > by) {
            ax = b.lng();
            ay = b.lat();
            bx = a.lng();
            by = a.lat();
        }
        // alter longitude to cater for 180 degree crossings
        if (px < 0) {
            px += 360;
        }
        if (ax < 0) {
            ax += 360;
        }
        if (bx < 0) {
            bx += 360;
        }

        if (py == ay || py == by) py += 0.00000001;
        if ((py > by || py < ay) || (px > Math.max(ax, bx))) return false;
        if (px < Math.min(ax, bx)) return true;

        var red = (ax != bx) ? ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)) : Infinity;
        var blue = (ax != px) ? ((py - ay) / (px - ax)) : Infinity;
        return (blue >= red);

    }

};
```

Here we have extended the functionality of google.maps.Polygon by defining a function with name ‘Contains’ which can be used to determine whether the latitude longitude provided in function parameter are within the polygon or not.
Here we make use of Ray-casting algorithm and developed a function using the same. After  doing this much of exercise now, we can check a point as follows:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(52.05249047600099, -0.6097412109375);
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({path:[INSERT_PATH_ARRAY_HERE]});
if (polygon.Contains(point)) {
    // point is inside polygon
}
```

For complete code and demo please go to: 
http://counsellingbyabhi.blogspot.in/2013/01/google-map-check-whether-point-latlong.html

Comment: Yes, ray casting is the way to go I think.  I actually utilized that algorithm myself via a python script.  My implementation can be found here:  http://gramsky.blogspot.com/2012/12/webservice-to-determine-if-latlong-is.html

Comment: I had to remove the bits that added 360 to negative coordinates for this to work properly around longitude 0.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go the Open Layers plugin; fetch it, and you can then even add whatever dynamic layer to your map and export.

*Before doing so, ensure you have your project CRS(EPSG) set to WGS84, and that 'on the fly' CRS transformation is enabled under your Project Properties settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you use third party program as geodjango, you can check out your point whether within a set of polygons or not. more info is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#contains).

```
contains

Availability: PostGIS, Oracle, MySQL, SpatiaLite

Tests if the geometry field spatially contains the lookup geometry.

Example:

Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__contains=geom)

Backend     SQL Equivalent
PostGIS     ST_Contains(poly, geom)
Oracle  SDO_CONTAINS(poly, geom)
MySQL   MBRContains(poly, geom)
SpatiaLite  Contains(poly, geom)
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but It might helpful in case SomeOne  didn't try Android-Map-Utils library. I have posted this Question's specific methods only for Android. Here you go:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988461/2054348